# Get touch events on a dialog that show itself while the finger was already touching the screen

Tags: android, view, dialog, touch

I have a view with a long click listener. This triggers the show of a fullscreen dialog. I need to capture touch events on said dialog (particularly `ACTION_UP`) but since the `ACTION_DOWN` was captured by the first view and was never released I don't get any events on the dialog.

Besides a listener on the view that tells the dialog when `ACTION_UP` happens, do you know another way of detecting `ACTION_UP` in this case from the dialog perspective?

Comment: Maybe you should release the long click listener (set it to null) after clicking (and set it back when dismissing the dialog box)

Comment: I'm not using a listener but the onTouchEvent method of the view. I howver tried setting a flag to return false instead of true on said method but the results were the same. I also tried to change all to listeners with also the same results. It was worth a try, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solved this?

Comment: No, my work with that application ended abruptly and I were free of being forced to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning a false on the OnLongClickListener so the event won't be consumed by the first view, and that might let your second dialog see the Click action.

Comment: Sadly, the onLongPress method of the GestureListener returns void, not boolean. Same thing with onLongPressListener.